# Windows Search Service - text saved in ansi (codepage 1251) format - search for non-english symbols gives no result

Tags: c#, windows, pdf, search, text

I've configured Windows Search Service to index the test folder c:\temp\test. There is file amsi.txt saved in ansi (codepage 1251) format with words "substring" and "Россия" in content. When I'm search for word "substring" - file is shown in results. When I'm searching for word "россия" - nothing is shown if search result.

The same behavior with PDF file - there is file test.pdf containing the same words. The search result contain this file only if I search for "substring" word.

I've configured search service to search inside content always. I've configured service to index file content for .pdf and .txt extensions. I've re-indexed folder after that. The latest version of pdf IFilter for my x64 system installed (from Adobe).

Also, I've implemented application to reproduce situation and performed the relevant query with LCID specified as 1049 and tried to encode the query as ansi (codepage 1251). The results the same - russian word not found in pdf and ansi test files.

How to search for non-english words inside ansi or pdf documents using windows search services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved for text files  as follow. Does anyone knows what to do with pdf?

I've implemented the following ugly conversion and converted the string to search for as it done by ugly Windows Search Service (c# code):

```
 public static class Helper
    {
        public static string UnicodeToUglycode(string unicodeString, string lang)
        {

            var ansiCodePage = GetCodepage(lang);

            var unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            var ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(ansiCodePage);

            var bytesUnicode = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);          
            var bytesansi = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ansi, bytesUnicode);

            // try udly recoding lie WSS
            var uglycode = AnsiToUglycode(bytesansi);

            return uglycode; 
        }        


        /// <summary>
        /// This is done as ugly Windows Search Service do
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ansiBytes">Correct ansi values</param>
        /// <returns>ugly converted to unicode string</returns>
        public static string AnsiToUglycode(byte[] ansiBytes)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < ansiBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                var ch = ansiBytes[i].ToString("X2");
                ch = ch.Insert(0, "00");
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(ch, 16);
                builder.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value));                
            }

            var ugly = builder.ToString();
            return ugly;
        }    

        public static int GetLcid(string lang)
        {
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
            return cultureInfo.TextInfo.LCID;
        }

        public static int GetCodepage(string lang)
        {
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
            return cultureInfo.TextInfo.ANSICodePage;
        }
    }
```